# Code First Entity Framework 5 and Oracle Data Client 11.2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do Code-First development with EF 5.0 and Oracle Data Client 11.2.0. I have been reading online that 12c version of Oracle Client supports Code first but I am wondering if 11.2.0 supports it as well. I got my code to work Database-First approach but for the Code-First approach its asking me to set Sql Generator which I cannot find within Oracle Client 11.2.0. Am I doing something wrong or does oracle client 11.2.0 not support Code-First Approach?

Comment: It's not the Oracle client but the ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) version you are using. See here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html

Comment: my ODAC version is 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3) I mentioned above I seen that 12c Beta supports code first but don't know if that is the only version that supports it or if the others do as well and if the others do what am I missing.